# Toggletip is moving when page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have toggleTip. When I select any string in the webpages a toggletip should appear. For the pages having single div for entire page and scrollability as well it's working fine when I scroll. But for the pages like gmail or any mail windows in which there is scrollabilty for a particular (not for entire page) div at that point the toggletip is moving away from the selected string. Can you please me out with this?

Below are images illustrating the issue:

When I click the toggleTip is next to the selected string

[image]

When I scroll in the same page the toogletip is moving

[image]

```css
.toolTipContainer {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: #0073C4 !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  background: #F1F3F5 !important;
  padding: 8px !important;
  line-height: 12px !important;
  z-index: 500;
  border: 1px solid #cccc !important;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}

.highlight a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  color: #164794 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  background: #F1F3F5 !important;
  padding: 8px !important;
  line-height: 12px !important;
  z-index: 500;
  border: 1px solid #cccc !important;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}
```

```html
<div className={styles.highlight} style={toggletipDisplay}>
  <a className={styles.toggleTipContainer} style={toggletipStyle}>
    "example"
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Comment: hi Aravind Thanks for the reply please find the image uploaded above may be you can get the idea . i need the toogletip should constant postion even we scrolls the page ... the snapshot is from gmail.com i opened a mail and clicked on some text

Comment: where you gave `position:relative`?

Comment: If i use position: relative in the parent div or child one even the tooltip is losing the position.

Comment: Please share a code snippet